# 画面の物理的な大きさを判断する方法

Tags: android

Android において画面の物理的な大きさは、
`xdpi` / `ydpi` と `width` / `height` (いずれもpixel) を使って計算できます。
しかし `dpi` は必ずしも正確な値とは限りません。
例えば、Galaxy S III の`dpi`値は不正確です。

実際の大きさを直接取得する手段はないでしょうか？

又は、Android TV や HDMI出力の場合に、
テレビの大きさそのもの、或るいは、
その大きさを推定するためにモデルIDを取得する手段はあるでしょうか？

どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: そもそも論になってしまうのですが、物理的な大きさを取得して何に利用するのでしょうか？

Comment: 実物大の画像を表示する為です。物理的な大きさを取得したら出来ると思います。

Answer (score 3):

メーカー名とモデル名は以下のように取得できます。

import android.os.Build;

String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
String model = Build.MODEL;

Comment: そうですね、でもAndroid TV、又はHDMI出力の場合は通じないと思います…